# LGPL/public-domain equivalent of Apache log4cxx?

Tags: licensing, log4cxx

Is there an equivalent of [Apache log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/license.html) that can be embedded in a distributed proprietary package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache license allows you to use this package in your product even if it is closed source and commercial. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License

Alternatively take a look at [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/) which is under LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

Log4cplus is a nice alternative.

In its production release 1.0.4 it misses AsyncAppender, but that is present in the coming 1.1 (I don't know when that is released).

We just switched from log4cxx to log4cplus since log4cxx depends on libapr/libaprutil (nice Apache 2 license) which on my Ubuntu 10.04 again depends on libdb4.8.so.  The license for libdb4.8 not fit closed source commercial applications without buying a license from Oracle. From `/usr/share/doc/libdb4.8/copyright`:

> ... For a license to use the Berkeley DB software under conditions
>   other than those described here, or to purchase support for this software,
>   please contact Oracle at berkeleydb-info_us@oracle.com.
>
> ...(some more text)
>
> **3. Redistributions in any form must be accompanied by information on
>       how to obtain complete source code for the DB software and any
>       accompanying software that uses the DB software**. ...